# Increasing and decreasing the quantity of products in Prestashop

Tags: javascript, prestashop

I want to add increasing and decreasing of quantity in my product list. This is my code in Prestashop 1.6:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">// The button to increment the product value
$(document).on('click', '.product_quantity_up', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        fieldName = $(this).data('field-qty');
        var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
        if (!allowBuyWhenOutOfStock && quantityAvailable > 0)
                quantityAvailableT = quantityAvailable;
        else
                quantityAvailableT = 100000000;
        if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal < quantityAvailableT)
                $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1).trigger('keyup');
        else
                $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(quantityAvailableT);

        $('#quantity_wanted').change();
});
 // The button to decrement the product value
$(document).on('click', '.product_quantity_down', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        fieldName = $(this).data('field-qty');
        var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
        if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 1)
                $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal - 1).trigger('keyup');
        else
                $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(1);

        $('#quantity_wanted').change();
});</script>
<div class="hide quantity_wanted_flatlist">
<p id="quantity_wanted_p">
    <input type="number" min="1" name="qty" id="quantity_wanted" class="text" value="1" />
    <a href="#" data-field-qty="qty" class="btn btn-default button-minus product_quantity_down">
        <span><i class="icon-minus"></i></span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" data-field-qty="qty" class="btn btn-default button-plus product_quantity_up">
        <span><i class="icon-plus"></i></span>
    </a>
    <span class="clearfix"></span>
</p>
</div>
```

Like you see I have js and input filed called quantity_wanted. When I press + or - nothing happened. This is a source code.

Comment: First of all you have an error in console: ReferenceError: allowBuyWhenOutOfStock is not defined
Also, you can't have duplicate ids. In other words, you have all ids quantity_wanted, but they should more like quantity_wanted_{$id_product}. and even if you change the quantity in the text box since the link in the add to cart has quantity 1, will still add 1.

Answer (score 0):

As per link shared by you, your code is working. Quantity is incremented as well as decremented. But When we click on any (-) or (+) button of any corresponding product then quantity change is reflecting in all products.

This is happening just because you have given the same id name to all input field as result when you update the quantity for any product then update is reflecting in all products.

Solution:

```
// The button to increment the product value  
$(document).on('click', '.product_quantity_up', function(e){  
   e.preventDefault();  
   fieldName = $(this).data('field-qty');   
   var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());  
   if (!allowBuyWhenOutOfStock && quantityAvailable > 0)  
      quantityAvailableT = quantityAvailable;  
   else  
      quantityAvailableT = 100000000;  
   if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal < quantityAvailableT)  
      $(this).closest('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1).trigger('keyup');  
   else  
      $(this).closest('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(quantityAvailableT);  
});  

// The button to decrement the product value  
$(document).on('click', '.product_quantity_down', function(e){  
   e.preventDefault();  
   fieldName = $(this).data('field-qty');   
   var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());   
   if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 1)  
      $(this).closest('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal - 1).trigger('keyup');  
   else  
      $(this).closest('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(1);  
});
```

The above code will find the nearer quantity input box having name **qty** (obtained from "field-qty" attribute of button) and set the calculated quantity.